# How to dynamically add RowDefinition or ColumnDefinition to a Grid with binding?

Tags: wpf, templates, grid, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create a table with a variable number of rows and columns. I'm doing this with an `ItemsControl` which has a `Grid` as its `ItemsPanel`. And I know I can set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` of each item through its `ItemContainerStyle`. But I don't know how to change **the number of rows and columns and their sizes** when I can't access the Grid by its name.

---

### Question:

How can you modify `RowDefinitions` or `ColumnDefinitions` of a `Grid` in run-time **without any code-behind** using Binding?

---

This is the XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl Name="myItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid Name="myGrid">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- unknown number of rows are added here in run-time -->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!-- known number of columns are added here in run-time -->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style.../>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I tried to add some `RowDefinition` in code behind but I couldn't find a way to gain access to `myGrid` by its name (or any other way) since it is inside an `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

I'm wondering if is there any way to programmatically **add or modify `RowDefinitions` in run-time**?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for a `Grid` that modify the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` when those properties are set or changed.

It will allow you to write your `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding MaxGridRow}"
      local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="3" />
```

Then just expose a property from your `ViewModel` which returns the largest row number in the `Cells` collection.

You can find a detailed implementation of those properties [on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel relieved:) and by the way there was a tiny mistake in the last two methods. I changed them to : GetStarColumns(grid).Split(',');

Comment: @Bizz Thank you :) The first time I copied the code to wordpress it got rid of all special characters and I must have replaced the single quotes with double quotes by mistake. The extra `.ToString()` was there because the star columns/rows used to be an integer before I needed multiple star columns one day and decided to update it to a string

Comment: How defined local in xaml?

Comment: @arund Usually something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace"` in the `<Window>` tag. It tells WPF to use the term "local" as a shortcut to point to the XML NameSpace `MyProjectNamespace`

Comment: Thanks for update @Rachel ..i have used UniformGrid instead of Grid and binded rows.    [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627127/bind-dynamically-number-of-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate?noredirect=1#comment74311216_43627127

Answer (score 9):

If you had access to the grid from code-behind you could do this:

```
var rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
rowDefinition.Height = GridLength.Auto;
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
```

Comment: This won't help. I can't access `myGrid` by its name from within code.

Comment: You can't access *whatever it is* when it is the ItemPanelTemplate of an ItemsControl. @WtFudgE you are probably doing something else than that.