# How can I display one dimensional ObservableCollection as matrix in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have an one dimensional ObservableCollection. How can I display it as a multi-dimensional collection (Matrix)?

E.g: I have list of images (urls) I want to display it so there would be three images in a row and as many rows as count/3 will be equal to.

I found how I can bound two dimensional list to a grid, but nothing like I want.

Is this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can by `overriding` the `ItemsPanel` for your `ItemsControl` like this -

```
<ItemsControl>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Ok, but how it will know how many items in a row and how many rows just by binding? or I need manually initialize all the items...?

Comment: Instead use `UniformGrid` and specify the number of rows and columns as per your need. See the updated answer.

Comment: So, don't set the `Row` field. It will be set dynamically based on the number of items in your collection.

Comment: Say if you have `24` items then it will automatically create `8` rows of `3` columns each.

Comment: Either you can omit setting both `Rows` and `Columns`. UniformGrid arrange the items itself as per the available height and width.

Comment: instead of uniform grid you can use normal grid and set the number of columns and rows dynamically as Rachel said here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate

Comment: `Rows` and `Columns` can be set dynamically here through `Binding`. Rows and Columns are normal DP's which supports binding too.. :)