# Uniform Grid in ItemPanel Template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Say I have something like this code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blabla}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

<Data Template>
    <Button Command="{Binding blablaComamnd}"></Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

From what I understand, the uniformgrid will display 64 buttons in a wrap-panel like order to the blabla command of the object inside the blalbla data structure.

Is there a way to specify which item goes to which coordinates in the grid such as based ideally on Binding found in the `blabla` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify which item goes into which cell you need to use normal `Grid` and change `ItemContainerStyle` for `ContentPresenter`, which is items wrapper for `ItemsControl`, to bind `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` to your view model

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blabla}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding blablaComamnd}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

where `Column` and `Row` are properties of the same view model which contains `blablaComamnd`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. Do you know what I could do if  I wanted to bind the number of rows/columns to the ViewModel aswell?

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do it but you should be able to achieve it with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate) question.