# Merge columns if a property is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpfdatagrid

I have a class with some string properties and each class is displayed as a row in a data grid. Each property has a column of its own. If two adjacent properties are empty, I would like to merge those two columns for that particular row. I am open to using a datagrid or a listview as long as it does the job. E.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    string name { get; set;}
    string age { get; set;}
    string sex { get; set;}
    double income { get; set;}
}
```

[image: Merged Column]

Comment: I do not see the result of your merge, may you also add it to your question?

Comment: Guys its right there in the image. Doe has empty strings for age and sex, so I would like the line in row to disappear, i.e. merge the two columns for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use an ItemsControl for these kinds of situations. My suggestion is to use a Grid as ItemsPanel and instead of say 100 instances of MyClass, implement a Cell class and use 400 of them (each for one cell) and set their exact row and column in code.

You will need a GridHelper which you can find it [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate)

```
public class Cell
{
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public int ColumnSpan { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public CellType CellType { get; set; } //you can also add an enum for CellType
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllCells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid 
                v:GridHelper.ColumnsCount="{Binding TotalColumns}"
                v:GridHelper.RowsCount="{Binding TotalRows}">
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=RowIndex}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnIndex}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnSpan}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you need different types of cells, you can add this to the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CellType}" Value="NumericCellType">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource templateNumericCell}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CellType}" Value="GeneralCellType">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource templateGeneralCell}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Or else you can implement a single template:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Data}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I forgot to add ColumnSpan which I did now

Comment: Hey Bizz, thanks for your answer. Btw, how do u get the DataGrid like look?

Comment: It all depends on your preference, e.g. you can use DataGridColumnHeader for the first row cells, and use a TextBox with a Border for the other cells. a border with full span (ColumnSpan=4) as the background of a full row which is invisible and has a trigger on mouseOver to turn it to visible and so on.