# Dynamic Grid width for dynamically generated elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The following code gives the result that we see a divided Grid on 4 elements according to the schedule. Each column is filled with color.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF7E7738">
    <Grid Width="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Green"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Blue"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Background="Pink"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Below I wrote a code that should do the same.

```
public ObservableCollection<Grid> ConnectorItemsGridX { get; set; }

public void DrawConnectors()
{
    Grid mainGrid = new Grid();
    mainGrid.Width = Double.NaN;

    ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

    ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd2.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

    ColumnDefinition cd3 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd3.Width = new GridLength(0.6, GridUnitType.Star);

    ColumnDefinition cd4 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd4.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

    mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
    mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);
    mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd3);
    mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd4);

    Grid tb1 = new Grid();
    tb1.Background = Brushes.Beige;

    Grid tb2 = new Grid();
    tb2.Background = Brushes.DarkSeaGreen;

    Grid tb3 = new Grid();
    tb3.Background = Brushes.MistyRose;

    Grid tb4 = new Grid();
    tb4.Background = Brushes.Violet;

    mainGrid.Children.Add(tb1);
    mainGrid.Children.Add(tb2);
    mainGrid.Children.Add(tb3);
    mainGrid.Children.Add(tb4);

    Grid.SetColumn(tb1, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(tb2, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(tb3, 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(tb4, 3);


    ConnectorItemsGridX = new ObservableCollection<Grid>();
    ConnectorItemsGridX.Add(mainGrid);
}
```

Code from the XAMl file to load Grid.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF7E7738">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsGridX}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Why do not I see the result?

It seems to me that such a solution has a problem with downloading the width of the Grid which is higher.

If you type in a fixed value of type `mainGrid.Width = 200;` everything is displayed.
The window size may change more dynamically have a width equal to a grid above.
Is there anything I need to include in the code which is not used in the XAML version?

Comment: I was editing the first part of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemsControl doesn't show Grids, because they don't have Children elements.
(Add line `tb4.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "100500" });` for example and you will see Violet grid).

It happens due to `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` and `StackPanel` as Items panel. Both settings arrange minimal width 0 to Grid.

this works:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItemsGridX}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: columns]

I suggest to study these posts for inspiration for dynamic Grid columns:

[A Simplified Grid Markup for Silverlight and WPF
 by Colin Eberhardt](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/12/21/a-simplified-grid-markup-for-silverlight-and-wpf.html) (external)

[How can I dynamically add a RowDefinition to a Grid in an ItemsPanelTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate)

Comment: And it actually works. The problem was `StackPanel` in `<ItemsPanelTemplate>`