# Limit UniformGrid to a max of N items

Tags: wpf

I've just discovered UniformGrid to automatically add items and reorder them. Is there a way of having max number of item (for example six) or have I to perform this check when I've to add an item?

Something as

```
  private void OnAddCommandExecute()
    {
        IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewModelFactory>();

        CameraModel model = new CameraModel();
        model.Name = $"Camera_{cameraCount}";

        var camera = viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<CameraViewModel>(model, null);

        if(count<=6)
        {
            Cameras.Add(camera);

            cameraCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: UniformGrid doesn't have a property to set its maximum element size. Is your approach not working?

Comment: you might wanna check this out https://stackoverflow.com/q/9000549/366064