# How to reach my ColumnDefinition Width property from code behind

Tags: wpf, storyboard

So i have this `Grid`:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<ColumnDefinition x:Name="IsSelectedColumnDefinition" Width="0"/>
                                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="780"/>
                                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This `Grid` is inside `DataTemplate`:

```
<GridViewColumn>                                                          
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             // MY GRID
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

So as you can see i have this `x:Name="IsSelectedColumnDefinition"` but still from code behind i cannot reach it.

All i want to do is start this `Storyboard` from my `Button` click `Event`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="EnlargeWidth">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                     From="0" To="30" 
                     DecelerationRatio=".9" 
                     Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>

private void toggleButtonEnableOptions_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

**Button Event**

```
{
    Storyboard storyboard = Resources["IsSelectedGrigWidth"] as Storyboard;
        if (storyboard != null)
            storyboard.Begin(IsSelectedColumnDefinition); // HERE i cannot reach this **IsSelectedColumnDefinition**
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically add a RowDefinition to a Grid in an ItemsPanelTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000549/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-rowdefinition-to-a-grid-in-an-itemspaneltemplate)

Comment: I do not have this GridHelpers after local: (xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationName")

Comment: You need to add the source code to your project. it is provided in the answer. One more thing, these two questions are a bit different but I marked it as a duplicate because their solutions are the same (which is: there is no way to reach it and you need a grid helper to do it for you).

Comment: What source code ?

Comment: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/   it is provided in the answer.