# Justified Alignment and Centering woes in WPF ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I have a requirement where I need to align some buttons within a fixed area of the screen.  The chosen layout behaves/looks as follows;

[image: alignment requirements]

Specifically, I need a 3 button layout where the buttons reach the edges, a 2 button layout that has equals spacing between buttons and to the edge of the container, and a single button layout that's just simply centred.

I've tried/considered;

- Negative margin on container, positive margin on buttons.  (Problem is that the "2 button" layout does not have equal spacing)
- Manually calculating the margins for each control based on the number of elements in the collection using IValueConverters (Problem is that it seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve, lots of maths..)
- Creating 3 separate layouts and choosing the correct one based on collection size.  (Problem because it feels so, so, so very hacky)

Key Points:

- For layout 2, the gaps between the buttons should be equal to the size of the gap that reaches to the edge of the container (see the second layout in image).
- There is a logic swap between layout 2 and 3, layout 3 doesn't have "outside gaps", it only has gaps between each button.
- There is no 4 layout, no requirement for it.

So my question is:
**What's the "correct" way to achieve this spacing requirement?**  I'm looking for a simple and fairly standard way to do it.

Conclusion:

I thought it might be interesting to note that I ended up not being able to do this.  The mathsy solution and the "custom control" solutions would have worked if I'd tried harder, but I ended up taking the easy route and just "centralised a listview" and had done with it.

Comment: Maybe you could change [UniformGrid Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/UniformGrid.cs,fd8042c6510b4f30) to behave as you want. I think you can't run from math in this case.

Comment: @0xaryan Thanks for the suggestion - I've also provided that same advise to people in the past, to modifying WPF source code.  Unfortunately that's not possible in my scenario.

Comment: Couldn't that be achieved using `Grid` and defining dynamic spacing (using `*` notation) ?

Comment: @scharette Afraid not - the content of the grid columns needs to be included in the calculation of the gaps, it's not based on cell size, it's based on item size, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a new Panel named `DanRaysonPanel`.

**Edited:**

```
class DanRaysonPanel : ItemsControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a Grid as ItemsPanel
    /// </summary>
    public Grid GridContainer { get; set; }

    public void Refresh() => OnItemsChanged(null);

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var grid = GridContainer;

        if (grid == null) return;

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        if (Items.Count == 1) return;

        if ((Items.Count & 1) == 0) // Element count is even
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count * 2 + 1; i++)
            {
                if ((i & 1) == 1)
                {
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
                    Grid.SetColumn(Items[i / 2] as UIElement, i);
                }
                else grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }
        }
        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count * 2 - 1; i++)
            {
                if ((i & 1) == 0)
                {
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
                    Grid.SetColumn(Items[i/2] as UIElement, i);
                }
                else grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now add an instance of this panel to your view:

```
  <local:DanRaysonPanel x:Name="RaysonPanel">
    <local:DanRaysonPanel.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:DanRaysonPanel.ItemsPanel>

    <Button Width="100" Height="50" />

</local:DanRaysonPanel>
```

That `ItemsPanel` should declare it's `ItemsPanel` property explicitly. But you can edit the items as you want (Manual or Programmatically).

For the final step, you need to handle `Grid_Loaded` event.

```
  private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaysonPanel.GridContainer = sender as Grid;
        RaysonPanel.Refresh();
    }
```

P.S. The only that made this code too long is that `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` doesn't give you the declared `Grid` in code-behind. If you found a way for that, you can make this code much simpler.

Comment: Having tried this one, it's extremely close to being the right answer.  There's one anomaly, when it's the 1-button layout it'll left align iirc.  I did have to debug it a little as the `Items[i / 2] as UIElement` was failing with the way I was databinding it (I was databinding to a list of strings).

Comment: @DanRayson Anomaly can fix easily, just add `if (Items.Count == 1) return;` above the main `if` in `OnItemsChanged` event handler. Code already modified to fix this.

Comment: @DanRayson `Grid.SetColumn` requires a `UIElement` as parameter, not a `string`. You might need to wrap your string into to a `TextBlock` before binding it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Margin="-40,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid 
                  Columns="{Binding ListCount, Converter={StaticResource PlusOne}}" 
                  Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-40,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="80" Height="55" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

PlusOne is a converter that returns its input + 1

*Note that, `ItemContainerStyle` is used to move each item of `ItemsControl` to its proper position. `Left` and `Right` margins of `ItemsControl`, as well as `Right` field of the margin, should be equal to negative of half the width of each item defined in `ItemTemplate`.*

*Another note that, you can also use a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007442/366064) to have a bindable `ColumnDefinitions`. However, it takes WAY more effort than the provided code*

Comment: It's close, but not quite.  The solution you've shown doesn't scale the gaps correctly depending on container size..   I've made a test app with your suggestion, and I can see the layout isn't quite as I asked for, close, but not quite.

Comment: As an example: https://imgur.com/mebdv4m  You can see the two outer buttons aren't placed at the sides of the container, they're floating further inward.

Comment: @DanRayson yes I understand. That can be fixed using a `Margin` on `ItemsControl`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not...  There's a lot of strange things happen when you start resizing the container...

Comment: @DanRayson I found the problem. set the margin of `ItemsControl` to `-40,0` instead of `40,0` and it should work now. Oh wait. you need to replace `List.Count()` with a bindable property as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the buttons in a StackPanel and have the left margin of the Buttons define the spacing, but make the first button 0. Center the StackPanel with HoriztonalAlignment.

Comment: How would you calculate/arrive at the correct widths for the margins?

Comment: the way I read the drawing is the margins are "fixed", maybe that's not true. Certainly can calculate it as the other method, but that's not how I interpreted the requirements.

Comment: I've updated the question in the hope it's more explanatory.  Thanks.